# i can not use my proxy with http:username:password@host:port

Tags: apify

**Im getting this error while using custom proxy url... in the above formate..  My proxy does not support http:// format** **adding http:// gives authentication error 407**
RequestError: connect ENOENT username:pass@host:5959
at ClientRequest. (C:\Users\Force\pupp\my-new-project\node_modules\got\dist\source\core\index.js:953:111)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:422:26)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:327:22)
at ClientRequest.origin.emit (C:\Users\Force\pupp\my-new-project\node_modules@szmarczak\http-timer\dist\source\index.js:39:20)
at onerror (C:\Users\Force\pupp\my-new-project\node_modules\agent-base\dist\src\index.js:117:21)
at callbackError (C:\Users\Force\pupp\my-new-project\node_modules\agent-base\dist\src\index.js:136:17)
at runMicrotasks ()
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
at PipeConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1141:16)

Comment: you need to provide your code, not just the error

Comment: this is apify issue error accuer during cheeriocrawling

Comment: it's only an apify issue if you're using apify proxy

Comment: this is my proxy configuration code issue only in this code

Comment: delete your credentials there. you're missing the protocol part of the url

Comment: const proxyConfiguration = await Apify.createProxyConfiguration({
        proxyUrls: [
            'http://cznf-roate:f3iux@p.webshare.io:1080'
        ]
    });  the point is  like this ulr my proxy throw some authentication error while without two slashes in protocol the above mention error thrown while the proxy is working fine in another application not with apify by the way credentials are fake. Please help

Comment: (http://) is added not showing in my mssg